# Postman - GUIDS

Tags: javascript, c#, api, postman

As part of my API call I need to pass in random ids in the body, currently I am creating the IDs using GUID in C# but its proving to be really time consuming as I need to test APIs in large batches. I am trying to figure out if it's possible to create a GUID in Postman on the fly and save them into a variable and pass it into require parameters through the API call.

I came across few resources like

1. [What is {{$guid}} used for in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851383/what-is-guid-used-for-in-postman)
2. https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/guid-in-postman/

First issue I am having is that I want to create the ID without the dash, so instead of `b3d27f9b-d21d-327c-164e-7fb6776f87b0` I want `b3d27f9bd21d327c164e7fb6776f87b0`.

Secondly, I want to save these into a environment variable and pass it where it's required e.g.

In body as raw text I need to pass:

```
{
    "clientID":{{id}},
    "clientpassword":{{password}},
}
```

In the 'Tests', I currently have this script but I can't manage to get it working.

```
let id = {{$guid}};
let password = {{$guid}};
```

I have created 2 global variables called id and password

Also, currently I have these in the 'Tests' section of the postman, I see there is also a pre-request script. In which should I put this?

EDIT
Also, another thing I am trying to do is, sometimes I need to search for a user by providing a client id in different places. Is it possible to put the id and password in one place where I can either update it manually or by running the guid, so that I don't need to update it in each API test I do but rather it should grab it from one place where I updated it.

Comment: Instead of GUID, if your looking for a random clientID and clientpassword you could use `{{$randomUserName}}` and `{{$randomPassword}}` instead

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this in the `Pre-request Script` sandbox:

```
let idGuid = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$guid}}')
let passwordGuid = pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$guid}}')

pm.variables.set("id" , idGuid.replace(/-/g, ''))
pm.variables.set("password" , passwordGuid.replace(/-/g, ''))
```

These would then resolve the variables that you have placed within the `request body`.

Not the most efficient solution but it would create the values you would like.

There are also a number of other fake data variables available for you to use in the application:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/#dynamic-variables

Comment: Yup, updated after seeing that it _could_ be confusing for people :)

Comment: Thanks, looks good. will try it out, do you know if the edited section is possible?

Comment: getting this error: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError: pm.variables.replaceIn is not a function

Comment: It's only a recent change so if you're not using the latest version of the native app, you will more than likely see this issue.

Comment: Will check and update PM. Do you know if the edited section of the post is doable?